# Passing multiple Perl variables to R

Tags: r, perl, object, hash, parameter-passing

**Intro**

I am currently working with an existing Perl/R project. I need to pass multiple variables from a Perl page to an R script. This project currently uses the example as shown bellow.

> var.pl --> test.R

**Question 1**

I was wondering if there is a more sufficient way to pass multiple variables. Maybe via a hash or an object?
For two reasons:

1. To pass only one argument instead of 10
2. To have some kind of identifier for each variable

**Question 2**

There is actually one more layer (index.pl a webpage) that uses a href to call the *var.pl*:

> index.pl --> var.pl --> test.R

This index.pl contains an  tag that calls the *var.pl* and passes parameters. The var.pl script doesn't set the variables to the strings as shown bellow but sets its variables to the passed parameters. Is it possible to call an R script (incl parameters) to go from index.pl straight to test.R?

**index.pl**

```
my $var1 = 'testA';
my $var2 = 'testB';
my $var3 = 'testC';
print '<a href="var.pl?a='.$var1.'&b='.$var2.'&c='.$var3.'">Go</a>';
```

**var.pl**

```
use CGI qw/:standard :html3/;
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = param('a');
my $b = param('b');
my $c = param('c');

my $cmd = "Rscript test.R $a $b $c"

open(PROG, "$cmd |");
while (<PROG>) {
    chomp;
}
close(PROG);
```

**test.R**

```
arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE);

a = arg[1]
b = arg[2]
c = arg[3]


# I will do something with the variables
```

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::R

Comment: Please show the `index.pl` script and how it calls `var.pl`. Just to clarify, are you asking if it is possible to transmit a hash from Perl to R using command line arguments? Or are you looking for some other way of passing data from Perl to R (for example a JSON file)?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I have added index.pl. As for the passing of data, it can be any way as long as it includes an initial Perl page (since I use a perl web page) and an R script target.

Comment: @Andrie If you do not want to use command line arguments, you could try to write a JSON file. Sorry, I am not familiar with R so I cannot say much on the R side, but a quick google search gave me [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-data-import-tutorial#javascript) tutorial for loading JSON in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have used this solution:**

I have created a table in MySQL where I insert all parameters. I created a datestamp + userid as a primary key that I pass to the R script. The R script uses the RMySQL library and retrieves all the parameters (with the given datestamp as parameter)

**Perl**

- Creates a $datestamp variable (datestamp + userid)
- Insert into database all variables with $datestamp as primary key
- my $cmd = "Rscript test.R $datestamp"

**R**

- Retrieves all variables from database.

> arg <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE);
>
> datestamp = arg[1]

part of the RMySQL section:

> sql = sprintf("select * from TEMP where id='%s';", datestamp)
> rs
> <-dbSendQuery(con, sql)